# React Actions using RxJS for parallel async calls

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, subscription, redux-observable

I am having an existing action that calls the api with list of IDs as querystring parameter and fetches the thumbnail response for the passed IDs. In some cases, count of IDs can be 150-200 records. Hence, I am working on making this APIs call batch based and run in parallel using `forkJoin` and `subscribe` methods of RxJs. I'm facing following 3 issues regarding the implementation.

1. I am able to get the batch based response in next method of subscribe. However, the action invoked in this function along with response is not getting invoked.
2. maxParallelQueries dont seems to be working as intended. All the fetchThumbnailObservables() are executed at once and not in the batches of 3 as set as constant/
3. How to handle return of observable so that mergeMap do not give syntax error . `Argument of type '({ payload }: IAction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: IAction, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.ts(2345)`

Here is my current code looks like. Any help would be great on this.

````
const getThumbnails: Epic<IAction, IAction, IStoreState> = (action$, state$) =>
    action$.ofType(ActionTypes.AssetActions.DATA.FETCH_THUMBNAILS).pipe(
        mergeMap( ({ payload }) => {
            
            const assetIds = Object.keys(payload);
            const meta = payload;

            const batchSize = 10;
            const maxParallelQueries = 3;
            
            const fetchThumbnailObservables : Observable<IThumbnailResponse>[] = [];

            for (let count = 0; count < assetIds.length; count += batchSize) {
                fetchThumbnailObservables.push(AssetDataService.fetchThumbnailData(assetIds.slice(count, count + batchSize)));
            }

             forkJoin(fetchThumbnailObservables)
            .pipe(mergeMap(fetchThumbnailObservable => fetchThumbnailObservable, maxParallelQueries)) // Issue 1 :  maxParallelQueries limit is not working
            .subscribe({ 
                complete: () => { }, 
                error: () => { },
                next: (response) => { 
                     // Issue 2 :  below action dont seems to be getting invoked
                    actions.AssetActions.receivedThumbnailsAction(response, meta) 
                },     
             });
    
            // Issue 3 :  How to handle return of observable 
            // Added below code for prevennting error raised by mergeMap( ({ payload }) => {
            return new Observable<any>();
        }),
        catchError((error) => of(actions.Common.errorOccured({ error })))
    );
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. I am able to get the batch based response in next method of subscribe. However, the action invoked in this function along with response is not getting invoked.

You mustn't call an action imperatively in redux-observable. Instead you need to queue them.
`actions.AssetActions.receivedThumbnailsAction(response, meta)` would return an plain object of the shape `{type: "MY_ACTION", payload: ...}` instead of dispatching an action. You rather want to return that object wrapped inside an observable inside `mergeMap` in order to add the next action to the queue. (see solution below)

> 2. maxParallelQueries dont seems to be working as intended. All the fetchThumbnailObservables() are executed at once and not in the batches of 3 as set as constant/

First guess: What is the return type of `AssetDataService.fetchThumbnailData(assetIds.slice(count, count + batchSize))`? If it is of type `Promise` then `maxParallelQueries` has no effect because promises are eager and start immediately when created thus before `mergeMap` has the chance to control the request. So make sure that `fetchThumbnailData` returns an observable. Use `defer` rather than `from` if you need to convert a Promise to an Observable to make sure that a promise is not being fired prematurely inside `fetchThumbnailData`.

Second guess: [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) is firing all the request so `mergeMap` doesn't even have the chance to restrict the number of parallel queries. I'm surprised that typescript doesn't warn you here about the incorrect return type in `mergeMap(fetchThumbnailObservable => fetchThumbnailObservable, ...)`. My solution below replaces `forJoin` with `from` and should enable your `maxParallelQueries`.

> 3. How to handle return of observable so that mergeMap do not give syntax error . Argument of type '({ payload }: IAction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: IAction, index: number) => ObservableInput'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.ts(2345)

This is not a syntax error. In an epic you have either the option to return an empty observable `return empty()` if no subsequent actions are intended or dispatch another action by returning an observable of type `IAction`. Here my (untested) attempt to meet your requirements:

```
const getThumbnails: Epic<IAction, IAction, IStoreState> = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.ofType(ActionTypes.AssetActions.DATA.FETCH_THUMBNAILS).pipe(
    mergeMap( ({ payload }) => {
            
      const assetIds = Object.keys(payload);
      const meta = payload;

      const batchSize = 10;
      const maxParallelQueries = 3;
            
      const fetchThumbnailObservables : Observable<IThumbnailResponse>[] = [];

      for (let count = 0; count < assetIds.length; count += batchSize) {
        fetchThumbnailObservables.push(
          AssetDataService.fetchThumbnailData(
             assetIds.slice(count, count + batchSize)
          )
        );
      }

      return from(fetchThumbnailObservables)
        .pipe(
          mergeMap(
            fetchThumbnailObservable => fetchThumbnailObservable,
            maxParallelQueries
          ),
          map((response) =>
            // dispatch action for each response
            actions.AssetActions.receivedThumbnailsAction(response, meta)
          ),
          // catch error early so epic continue on error
          catchError((error) => of(actions.Common.errorOccured({ error })))
        );
    })
  );
```

Please notice that I moved `catchError` closer to the request (inside the inner forkJoin Observable) so that the epic does not get terminated when an error occurs. [Error Handling - redux observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/ErrorHandling.html) This is so because when `catchError` is active it replaces the failed observable with the one that is returned by `catchError`. And I assume you don't want to replace the whole epic in case of an error?

And one thing: redux-observable handles the subscriptions for you so won't need to call `.subscribe` or `.unsubscribe` anywhere in your application. You just need to care a about the lifecycle of observables. Most important to know here is when does an observable start, what happens to it when it completes, when does it complete or what happens when an observable throws.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works like charm. Much appreciate the detailed explanation on this :)

Comment: I'm happy to help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Epics, but I think I can give you some hints about how to address this problem.

Let's start from the fact that you have an array of ids, `assetIds`, and you want to make an http call for each id with a controlled level of concurrency, `maxParallelQueries`.

In this case `from` function and `mergeMap` operator are yor friends.

What you need to do is

```
// from function transform an array of values, in this case, to a stream of values
from(assetIds).pipe(
  mergeMap(id => {
    // do whatever you need to do and eventually return an Observable
    return AssetDataService.fetchThumbnailData(id)
  }, maxParallelQueries) // the second parameter of mergeMap is the concurrency
)
```

In this way you should be able to invoke the http calls keeping the limit of concurrency you have established

Comment: Thank you for the quick help. How can we fetch the response for each observable and call some other action (In my case `actions.AssetActions.receivedThumbnailsAction(response, meta)`) with response as input data?

Comment: If I understand your intention, you can just another mergemap. This second mergemap will receive the emission from the first, which you can use to return your second observable.